# i am unable to install java on my machine please someone help me out

Tags: java

this is the output thrown when i typed java -version
he program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcj-4.4-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install

please suggest me an alternative to install java on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu Software Center and search for "OpenJDK Java 7". That's what I'm using and it has worked flawlessly for me so far!